# Can't map Samba share from CentOS to Win10 - error 67 "The network name cannot be found"

Tags: samba

I've just followed a guide on installing Samba, adding a samba user and configuring the smb.conf file

```
[global]
        workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775

[Stuff]
        path = /mystuff
        guest ok = no
        available = yes
        valid users = livingroom
        read only = no
        browsable = yes
        writeable = yes
```

On my Win10 machine I can \192.168.100.6 and get prompted for login (username livingroom) which it accepts.  I then see two folders in explorer - 'livingroom' and 'Stuff'

However when I double-click either of them it will try for a while before eventually failing with Error code: 0x80070043 - The network name cannot be found.

Any ideas why its saying the network name cannot be found when i'm using the IP address to access it?